# How to join a series of pandas type pandas.Timestamp with another series type datetime.time?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a series of `pandas.Timestamp` pandas with dates in `%Y-%m-%d` format and another series of `datetime.time` with hours.

I would like to join both series to have a date with its hour. Here a example of inputs:

```
from pandas import Series, Timestamp, to_datetime
import datetime

s1 = Series([Timestamp("2021-03-01"),Timestamp("2021-03-01")])
s2 = Series([datetime.time(0,0), datetime.time(0,15)])
```

The way I have found to do it is to first pass both series to String, join them and after that convert them to datetime but I think this is an inefficient way:

```
s3 = s1.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + " " + s2.astype(str)
to_datetime(s3)
```

Is there a more efficient way without having to do string conversions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the series `s2` to `timedelta` then add that with `s1`

```
s1 + pd.to_timedelta(s2.astype(str))
```

---

```
0   2021-03-01 00:00:00
1   2021-03-01 00:15:00
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of doing it without converting `s2` to `str`?

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any other concise and better way.